# Illustration softwares that can auto resize the canvas size by the size of the content?

Tags: windows, drawing, sketch

I'm currently use Libre Draw to sketch illustrations to import to my documents. However the canvas size (page size) is fixed by user's configuration, while I want it to flexibly resize it by the size of the content, so that the size of the words in the final exports is in uniform. For example, the sizes of the words in these two graphics are different:

[image]
[image]

Something like adding a padding of 5 px to the leftmost, rightmost, topmost, bottom-most pixels of sketch. Is there a program for it? It should work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Either Sketch app or Affinity Designer will support the kind of variable constraints and padding to which you refer.

They're both commonly used for UI & UX wireframing and design, and so have toolsets aimed at responsive web layout, including constraints highly similar to your description.

Comment: For starters, which one do you recommend? Which one is free?

Comment: @Ooker - sincere apologies - I missed the OS requirement in your posting - my fault. Sketch is Mac Os only, Affinity Designer is Win-Mac, and is not free, but is only moderate cost. I use both myself for UX design and other illustration tasks, and in general prefer Affinity Designer as a more effective general illustration tool, and I like the way the proportional constraints are done in Affinity, so can comfortably recommend it.
https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/